# change event not getting triggered with poltergeist

Tags: backbone.js, capybara, poltergeist, rspec3

I have 2 dropdowns and on change of first am prepopulating the second dropdown(which is been done in backbone).

```
  events: ->
    'change #client_id': 'selectedClientChange'

  selectedClientChange: (ev) ->
    @populateGroups $(ev.target.selectedOptions).val()
```

Written capybara specs for the same with poltergeist but change event is not getting triggered for some reason and spec is getting failed.

```
scenario 'it should populate the groups automatically', js: true, speed: :slow do
  click_link 'New Item'
  find('#name').set('Sample Item')
  page.execute_script("$('#client_id').val('testing').trigger('change')")
  select "#{client.name}", from: "client_id"
  groups = find('#group_id').all('option').collect(&:text)
  expect(groups.count).to eq 1
  expect(groups).to include pg.name
end
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this.

Comment: What error are you getting (and on which step of the scenario)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah sorry everyone. I see that there is an issue with  poltergeist which I found here https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/204. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Without details about the error you're getting this is mostly a guess - It's possible you're getting the groups before the change event from the select actually updates them.  You'd be better off using the have_select matcher since it will retry for a time to see if the field changes to match the requirements

```
select "#{client.name}", from: "client_id"
expect(page).to have_select('group_id', options: [pg.name])
```